# Make checkboxes choose content to present from a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I'm creating a website where the user is supposed to check a couple of checkboxes and then the site will present the data in a table.

I have been looking at this ["guide"](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1184333-Use-AJAX-to-filter-MySQL-results-with-multiple-checkbox-option&s=3528f621d8c939d7cee25268a884cdfd), but cant make it work on my page. I get no results on my index.php, and the submit.php just shows "Array[]"

This is what I have so far:

Index.php holds the checkboxes and the jQuery script.

Checkboxes is in a drop down menu, like this:

```
    <div id="menu">
      <div id="mainmenu"><a href="#" onclick="toggle('submenu1')">Gender</a></div>
      <div id="submenu1" style="display:none">
        <div id="submenu"><a href="#">
          <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">Male</a></div>
        <div id="submenu"><a href="#">
          <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female">Female</a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="mainmenu"><a href="#" onclick="toggle('submenu2')">Price range</a></div>
      <div id="submenu2" style="display:none">
        <div id="submenu"><a href="#">
          <input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="200">200-299$</a></div>
        <div id="submenu"><a href="#">
          <input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="300">300-399$</a></div>
        <div id="submenu"><a href="#">
          <input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="400">400-499$</a></div>
      </div>
```

jQuery script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script>
      function makeTable(data){
        console.log(data);
       var tbl_body = "";
          $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "";
            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
              tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            })
            tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
          })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getSnowboardFilterOptions(){
        var opts = [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
          if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.id);
          }
        });

        return opts;
      }

      function updateSnowboards(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#boards tbody').html(makeTable(records));
          }
        });
      }

      var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
     $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getSnowboardFilterOptions();
        updateSnowboards(opts);
      });

      checkboxes.trigger("change");
</script>
```

At last I have submit.php, which holds the php code for selecting the right stuff.

```
<?php 
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...', '...', '...');
  $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
  $qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($opts) - 1) . '?';
  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT gender, price_range, brand, model, rocker_type, flex, size_range, image FROM snowboards)");
  $statement -> execute($opts);
  $results = $statement -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($results);
  echo($json);
?>
```

Right now the SELECT query isn't specified, because I don't know how.

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong, or have better suggestion to solve it, please tell.

Comment: You should set the checkbox names as arrays first name="gender[]"
and ofcourse you have to receive an array in php since you have multiple checkboxes with the same name. So the $opts contains an array. print_r($opts); to see what you got.

Comment: if I helped you you could also vote my comment, thanks :)

Comment: I added the [] at every name in the checkboxes.

I also added print_r($opts); to the submit.php, but nothing prints.

Should I modify the submit.php further? Thanks.

Comment: comment out everything else in submit,php and just keep $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
 print_r($opts);

Comment: I noticed I should probably change value="male" to id="male"..?

Also "filterOps" to "getSnowboardFilterOptions"..?

Still after this, submit.php is blank when commenting out the rest.

Comment: to see the $opts, submit the form without ajax, dont just go to the url /submit.php

Also for the javascript dont hcang ethe id , just replace opts.push(this.id);
with opts.push($(this).val());

generaly you should use $(this) in your code, not just this, if you wan to attach jQuery functions to it

Comment: Can't make this work. Doesn't seem like submit.php gets input from the script.

Thanks for you help, Dimitris. Can't find the vote function you mentioned though.

Comment: chnage this data: {filterOpts: opts}, to data:getSnowboardFilterOptions(),